# Chrome Extension for selecting a text and save as a bookmark?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to code a chrome extension,Selected text of web page has to be saved in to extension similar as a bookmark.please help.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You more details like where you are having doubt or where you are stuck,etc.

Comment: I really do'nt know where i can get a similar code,is there any example codes?.

Comment: I suggest you to refer to the docs of chrome extension development. For your bookmark task you can refer to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html). It provide a detail explanation of each api along with examples.

Comment: I can create a bookmark folder using the below code but how it is possible to add a text or image selected from page automatically to bookmark folder. code is given below,                                    chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': '1',
                         'title': 'Extension bookmarks'},
                        function(newFolder) {

 
});